# How to solve error when using profvis package

Tags: r, profvis

Today I learned about the `profvis` package to make my code faster, from the identification of commands that are demanding more time. The example provided by the package (https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/) I can run normally, but when I try in my code, nothing happens, it appears: `(Sources not available)`. So I would like to know, what am I doing wrong?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(profvis)


   df1 <- structure(
  list(
    Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
           1, 1),
    date1 = c(
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC"
    ),
    date2 = c(
      "2022-01-05 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-05 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-06 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-06 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-07 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-07 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-08 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-08 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-09 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-09 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-10 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-10 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-11 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-11 00:00:00 UTC",
      "2022-01-12 00:00:00 UTC"
    ),
    Week = c(
      "Wednesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday",
      "Saturday",
      "Sunday",
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday"
    ),
    Category = c(
      "ABC",
      "EFG",
      "ABC",
      "EFG",
      "ABC",
      "EFG",
      "ABC",
      "EFG",
      "ABC",
      "EFG",
      "ABC",
      "EFG",
      "ABC",
      "EFG",
      "ABC"
    ),
    DR1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0),
    DRM0 = c(300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300,
             300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 0),
    DRM01 = c(300, 300, 300, 300, 300,
              300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 0),
    DRM02 = c(
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300
    ),
    DRM03 = c(
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300
    ),
    DRM04 = c(
      300,
      250,
      250,
      250,
      250,
      250,
      250,
      250,
      250,
      250,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300,
      300
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-15L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

 
profvis({
 
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DRM"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x,Id, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Id,Category,Week) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(ends_with("PV"), median),.groups = 'drop')
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Id','Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DRM\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(Id:Category, DRM01_DRM01_PV:last_col())

})
```

[image]

```
 #Larger database
    df1 <- data.frame( Id = rep(1:5, length=10000),
                       date1 =  as.Date( "2021-12-01"),
                       date2= rep(seq( as.Date("2021-01-01"), length.out=5000, by=1), each = 2),
                       Category = rep(c("ABC", "EFG"), length.out = 10000),
                       Week = rep(c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",
                                    "Saturday", "Sunday"), length.out = 10000),
                       DR1 = sample( 200:250, 10000, repl=TRUE),  
                       setNames( replicate(365, { sample(0:10000, 10000)}, simplify=FALSE),
                                 paste0("DRM", formatC(1:365, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0"))))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38542894/903061

Comment: Gregor, Is it a duplicate? This example above is not a function.

Comment: Ah, I suppose not. (Wasn't sure, that's why I didn't close it as a dupe.) Side note, I would put the data creation `df1 <- ...` before the `profvis` - it doesn't really matter how much time it takes to create the sample data.

Comment: I tried to reproduce... I got your same issue once, then I pulled the data creation out of `profvis()`, and when I rerun I get `Error in parse_rprof(prof_output, expr_source) :  No parsing data available. Maybe your function was too fast?` You might need to try with bigger data for it to take long enough to have something to profile.

Comment: Gregor, You say increase the number of `df1` information?

Comment: If you can get to my state where it says "Maybe your function was too fast", then yes.